# Using jquery to find last row in <ul> and apply a class

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

My unordered list floats each item so that 3 items appear on a single line.

I need to apply a certain style to the bottom line of items. I'm currently using ::nth-child pseudo classes, but the problem lies in that some of these lists have 1, 2, or 3 items on that last line.

How can I have jquery figure out which items are on the last row, and apply a class so I can apply a specific style to those items?

Comment: An example of your HTML structure would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best solution, but here's one using the mod operator to find the number in the last row:

http://jsfiddle.net/V8edM/

```
$('ul').each(function () {
    var $lis = $('li', this);
    var count = $lis.length;

    if (count < 4) {
        $lis.addClass('last-row');

    } else {
        var numberInLastRow = count % 3 || 3;
        $lis.eq(-1 * numberInLastRow - 1).nextAll().addClass('last-row');

    }
});
```

Edit- Updated to account for less than 4 items.

Comment: I think his problem is that he doesn't know how many items fit in each line, so the constant used with the modulo would be unknown, unless it is calculated based on the current DOM.

Comment: @LiorCohen First sentence in his question: _"My unordered list floats each item so that 3 items appear on a single line."_

Comment: I guess I'm generalizing the problem when I shouldn't. If he knows 3 is guaranteed, your answer should be accepted as correct. Removing mine anyways, since it's incomplete.

Comment: @LiorCohen I went with the assumption that he did know. If he doesn't, the question becomes much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is what I was looking for. How much more complicated would it be if I didn't know there was 3?

Comment: @JasonP: you owe me a cookie :P

Comment: @NWTech I would probably do some math comparing the width of the container with the width of the `li`s to determine how many fit in a row and continue from there. Be sure to account for margin, padding, and border. You may also need to recalculate when the window is resized, depending on layout.

Comment: @NWTech: you would need to use offsets for each of the child elements to check where lines break based on the Y value for each item, then group them by that Y value, get the greatest Y value and apply a CSS class to every element who's Y offset has that maxY value. Not rocket science, but be sure to check for edge cases.

Comment: Ok, so another question. My list has it's own class "jsrm-ul" so I changed "ul" to "ul.jsrm-ul". Each <li> already has a class, "odd" or "even"....so will this cause an issue when the script issues the new class?

Comment: No, `addClass()` doesn't touch existing classes on the element.

Comment: Thanks. Forgive my ignorance, I'm still learning jQuery. I assume the above code should be wrapped in `$(function() {`? Which I have it, but I can't seem to get it working =/

Comment: Yes, the code needs to be executed after the elements exist. If they exist when the page loads, just wrap the code in `$(function({...})` or `$(document).ready(function() {...})`